# Сумма квадратов. Можно ли написать короче?

Tags: java

Нужна программа, которая вычисляет сумму квадратов чисел от 1 до N

```
class Sum{  
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        int n = 3;  // В данном случае N = 3
        int res = 0;

        for(int b = 1; b < n; b++){
            res = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6;
        }

        System.out.println( res );
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще, даже схема Горнера дает столько же умножений: n(1+n(3+2n))/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть я чего-то не понимаю, но в какой зависимости находится **res** от **b**?

```
class Sum{  
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        int n = 3;  // В данном случае N = 3
        int res = 0;
        res = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6;
        System.out.println( res );
    }
}
```

Абсолютно тоже самое.

Comment: да, цикл здесь не нужен! ReinRaus, спасибо!

Comment: Сокращать, так сокращать

    int res = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6;

Последовательно проводя такие "сокращения" получим

    System.out.println(12);

Может быть требовалось в цикле

    res += b*(b+1)*(2*b+1)/6; // ???

Но, для n=3 все опять сводится к System.out.println(12); т.к. для b=1 и b=2 сомножитель (2*b+1)/6 дает 0 (поскольку считаем в целых).

Вот так.

Comment: avp, а как это можно в цикле написать?

Comment: Что именно ? res += b... ? Так у Вас цикл for(int b = ..., поставьте вместо res = n... res += b...

Comment: а зачем все это в цикле писать?  
    
    <?php
    $ave=0;
    echo '?';
    for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++) {
        $ave+=$i*$i;
        if ($ave!=$i*($i+1)*(2*$i+1)/6) echo $i.' ';
    };
    echo '!';
    ?>
Результат  
    
    ?!

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
class Sum{  
public static void main(String[] args){     
    int res = 0;
    for(int b = 1, n=3; b < n; b++, res = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6);
    System.out.println( res );
}
```

но зачем?

Comment: я про саму формулу, можно ли ее как-нибудь сократить?

Comment: @spectre, тонкий явовый юмор :)  
@Burunduk, Вам же сделали короче :)

Comment: ReinRaus, не спорю, вариант кода интересный, но мне бы сократить формулу, если это возможно :)